# How can i use promises in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I have three async ajax calls functions with callback functions for fetching info to the main page. Those functions are on another js file.

```
Ajax_GetUsers(Fetch_Users);
Ajax_GetContactTypes(Fetch_ContactTypes);
Ajax_GetCasePriorities(Fetch_CasePriorities);
```

After those three finish fetching the results i want to do one more call to this function :

```
Ajax_GetCaseData(selectedCaseId, Fetch_CaseData)
```

This is the code i created but still does not work . The Ajax_GetCaseData
sometimes is called before the others . How can i make sure that the Ajax_GetCaseData will be always executed after the other three asynchronous functions : 
Here is my Code :

```
$.when(Ajax_GetUsers(Fetch_Users),Ajax_GetContactTypes(Fetch_ContactTypes), 
       Ajax_GetCasePriorities(Fetch_CasePriorities))                        
 .then(function () {
      Ajax_GetCaseData(selectedCaseId, Fetch_CaseData);
});
```

Comment: You can't just work with callbacks as promises.

Comment: Understood. can you point me on how can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Have a look at the dupe